# Attempt to read property "url" on null - Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

Estoy buscando solución a este problema típico pero en mi caso no encuentro que sucede.
En otro proyecto con laravel 7 me funciona bien y no sé si es que en Laravel 9 algo ha cambiado.

Al querer mostar la imagen recibo el error: **Attempt to read property "url" on null**

```
<img class="h-48 w-full object-cover object-center" src="{{ Storage::url($property->images->first()->url) }}" alt="">
```

Llamada a la imagen:

```
@foreach ($category->properties as $property)
        
            <li class="bg-white rounded-lg shadow">
                <figure>
                    <img class="h-48 w-full object-cover object-center" src="{{ Storage::url($property->images->first()->url) }}" alt="">
                </figure>
            </li>
        
@endforeach
```

Modelo Property:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Image::class, 'imageable');
}
```

Modelo Image

```
public function imageable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

ENV

```
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
```

Filesystem

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path(),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],
```

Url en la base de datos:

```
properties/property/e4b313cfd483f7fe8560ba27fecbc32b.png
```

Comment: Que te devuelve **$property->images->first()->url** en texto? porque la llamada esta bien definida para Laravel 9. Es de verificar que es lo que se "imprime" dentro del `Storage::url(que se imprime acá?)`

Comment: Tal vez images está vacío.  Para evitar el error podrías intentar poniendo                     **@if ($property->images->first())**  antes de la llamada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he resuleto este error humano dado que había puesto mal el nombre de la clase en el seeder.

'imageable_type' => Property::class

(Golpe en la cabeza) No tenía Property sino el nombre del ejemplo en donde tome este fragmento de código.

Disculpen las molestias y gracias